# What is an $F$-rational section of a line bundle?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an algebraic variety over a field $F$. What is the definition of an ``$F$-rational section" of a line bundle? I can't find any references for this notion.

Comment: It might help if you could give some context - but I suspect here it's saying you have a morphism of $F$-schemes $X\rightarrow L$ (i.e. a section in the usual sense). The reason for this distinction, at least in the context I've seen, is that sometimes people work after base changing to the algebraic closure.